# DocumentDB SP with IN statement

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

My `DocumentDB SP`:

```
function getSetOfProductDetails(productIds) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product.productId IN ("+ productIds +")" ,
        function (err, feed, options) {
            if (err) throw err;

            // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
            // else take 1st element from feed
            if (feed) getContext().getResponse().setBody(feed);
        });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

My C# Code:

```
string productIdList = "'271762','288738','235521','266714'";
 List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
 try
 {
     productList = await  DocumentDBRepository<List<Product>>.ExecuteStoredProc("product","getSetOfProductDetails", productIdList );
}
```

DocumentDBRepository Code:

```
public static async Task<T> ExecuteStoredProc(string collectionId, string storedProcedureId, params object[] parameter)
        {
            ConnectToDatabase();
            StoredProcedureResponse<T> document = await _documentClient.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<T>(UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri(_databaseId, collectionId, storedProcedureId), parameter);
            return (T)(dynamic)document;
        }
```

The result set I receive in `productList` is blank, whereas there are documents in the `Collection`. Is this the right way of implementing the `IN` statement for `DocumentDB`?

Comment: I am guessing that the problem is in how it serializes the productIds array. You could try JSON.stingify(productIds) but I would first try building the SQL statement outside of your queryDocuments call and see how it sets serialized when the SQL statement is built.

Comment: You can just return the as-built SQL statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `SELECT * FROM product WHERE product.productId IN ("+ productIds +")` can get correct value that should be worked with your code. I test with your code and it works correctly on my side.

[image]

As you mentioned that the documents are in collection, please have a try to do troubleshot with following way:

1.Make sure the SQL can get the expected result. And the fields are case sensitive. As in the my Product model I used field ProductId, so In my case I used **product.ProductId** not **product.productId** to query. I query it with the Azure portal

[image]

2.Execute the stored procedure from the Azure portal

[image]

If both are worked, please have a try with you code again.

Comment: `DocumentDB` is **Case Sensitive** - lesson learnt Hard Way... Thanks a lot @Tom Sun - MSFT